# I want to map x y data with a raster grid at 0.5 degree scale, then count the number of x y points within each 0.5 cell

Tags: r, coordinates, gis, spatial, raster

I have global data showing the predicted range of a species as points. My aim is to count the number of occurrences in cells of 0.5 degrees resolution.

I figure I can do this by creating a Raster on the same coordinate system...

```r
rast <- raster(xmn= -180, ymn= -90, xmx = 180, ymx = 90, resolution = 0.5,
            crs = '+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ')
```

I need to count the number of x/y occurrences in each cell.

Most of the examples I have read use a count value from the data but my data doesn't have a count as each row is species specific. I think I need to create some sort of grid or net of 0.5 degrees and then use that to count the x/y points?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can use `rasterize` with `fun=count`

Comment: I also need to map the cells and colour them according to how many x y occurrences are within them...I'll read about rasterize and fun=count, I'm new to R.

Comment: When trying to use rasterize I need to put in a field but I don't have a field, just x and y, so it can't count anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `rasterize(..., fun = "count")`

Here's a reproducible example drawn from the docs (`?rasterize`).

```
library(raster)

# create a raster
r <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)
n <- 1000

# create some points
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(n) * 360 - 180
y <- runif(n) * 180 - 90
xy <- cbind(x, y)

# count the number of points in each raster cell
r0 <- rasterize(xy, r, fun = "count")

# visualize
plot(r0); points(xy, pch = 16, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

---

To check the resolution of a `RasterLayer`, use `res(raster_object)`. To modify that resolution use assignment:

```
x_res <- 100  # resolution in x
y_res <- 100  # resolution in y
res(raster_object) <- c(x_res, y_res)  # set the x,y resolution of the raster
```

Since you want 0.5 degree raster cells, first check what units your `crs` are in (e.g.- meters), calculate the x and y resolution in those units, and then assign that resolution to the raster. Also be aware the degrees of latitude vary slightly depending on whether you're closer to the equator or poles.

---

To visualize with ggplot, you can convert a `RasterLayer` object to a `data.frame` like so. Although I don't show it, you can add the points as another `geom_point` or `geom_sf` layer in the ggplot object.

```
# convert to data.frame and plot with ggplot
df <- as.data.frame(r0, xy=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = layer)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "white") +
  labs(fill = "Count") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I've got some fiddling to do with my data but that should do it! :):)

Comment: Welcome to the magic of Stack Overflow and congrats on asking your first question! If you believe that solves your problem, consider ["Accepting the answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).